# 東北弁 Pronunciation Question about Ch's

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I've been trying to learn Tohokuben and I have a question.

I'm interested in Tohokuben and recently found this website https://konnok3.sakura.ne.jp/dialect.html. I know pronunciation can vary all over the Northeast but I've heard that きゃきゅきょ is often pronounced ちゃちゅち. But I've also heard that つぁつぉつぇare possible. Is is that きゃきゅきょ = ちゃちゅち but ちゃちゅち = つぁつつぉ

E.g.

客 = ちゃく but 着 = つぁく

or should both of these groups be pronounced the same? If so, when or where is each used?

E.g.

客 and 着 = ちゃく in some areas but 客 and 着 = つぁく in others?

Comment: I lived in Morioka some 25 years ago, and at that time, probably in part due to modern media and the bullet train, the きゃきゅきょ series were pronounced //kja・kju・kjo//, same as for standard Tokyo dialect.  Dunno about elsewhere in Iwate or the rest of the Tōhoku.